# D3DKMTCreateAllocation return code

Tags: windows, graphics, directx, driver, d3dx

In a driver I am debugging there is a call to `D3DKMTCreateAllocation`. The error I receive is int (-1071775735) or 0xc01e0009 which is of type `NTSTATUS`.

I am trying to figure out this error but cannot find anything. It doesn't map to any of these:

```
STATUS_SUCCESS  
STATUS_DEVICE_REMOVED  
STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER  
STATUS_NO_MEMORY  
STATUS_NO_VIDEO_MEMORY
```

How can I identify the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may have stumbled upon an error code (`STATUS_GRAPHICS_DRIVER_MISMATCH`) that is defined incorrectly in available documentation (see [NTSTATUS values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx), shown as 0x401E0117); but it exists in the header file `<ntstatus.h>` in the Windows Platform SDK and matches your value.

My installed copy of the Windows SDK (v7.0, Windows 7 / .NET 3.5sp1) describes it as follows (line 13743):

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_GRAPHICS_DRIVER_MISMATCH
//
// MessageText:
//
// The kernel driver detected a version mismatch between it and the user mode driver.
//
#define STATUS_GRAPHICS_DRIVER_MISMATCH  ((NTSTATUS)0xC01E0009L)
```

Other D3D functions have this symbol listed but not the value. Here are links to the documentation, along with the quoted text.

[DxgkDdiOpenAllocation @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559699%28VS.85%29.aspx)
STATUS_GRAPHICS_DRIVER_MISMATCH - "*The display miniport driver is not compatible with the user-mode display driver that initiated the call to DxgkDdiOpenAllocation (that is, supplied private data to the display miniport driver).*"

[DxgkDdiCreateAllocation @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559606%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
STATUS_GRAPHICS_DRIVER_MISMATCH - "*The display miniport driver is not compatible with the user-mode display driver that initiated the call to DxgkDdiCreateAllocation.*"